# How to search on a website's search bar in WebView by using EditText?

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext, searchview, searchbar

I have an EditText and a WebView. The WebView loads Amazon website when initialized. When I enter a query in EditText I want the Amazon website search for the query(search on the website's search bar). Any help is highly appreciated.
Here is my code

```
webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    url = "https://amazon.com";
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Hi, You have to reload the URL with the text searched on edit text, like this `https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=<searched key>` replace searched key with your edit text value.

Comment: @Archana Thank you. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just navigate the WebView to the search url from Amazon:

https://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=***search keyword(s)***

```
final String searchURL = "https://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=";
String keywords = "something";
view.loadUrl(searchURL + keywords);
```

Maybe you need to convert the keywoards to an URL conform format, especially when containing special chars.

Comment: The page loads correctly, but the it has empty search bar.

Comment: For me in the Firefox browser it works, the search bar is showing the keyword. Is this really important for you? Then you would have to modify the webview's content.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for the answer.